# CSS Button styling - Need some help -html css RADIO BUTTON LINK

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button

I need some help with this button styling ,

see link (clikc on edit code)
[enter link description here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/f2ezu8z9)
as you can see is the add to cart text out of line ... and does the 'imput' command fill up my button.
how can i center the text back into the button?
width: 100%;
    }

please advice

thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors and bad tag formatting in your code. Tags should also not overlap (first open, last closed), like in the following part of your code:

```html
</div>
</button></h2>



</div></div></body></form></button>
```

This not valid formatting.

Each tag has a specific use, for example:

`<h2>` tags are used to define second HTML headings of a page.

They should not contain anything else than the title of the section they define.

The closing body tag `</body>` can't be followed be any by anything except `</html>` tag.

You should probably rewrite the whole thing.